# Node-dev doesn't run continuously

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-dev

I've got small problem with node-dev. I installed it accordingly to directions in readme, and it runs when I type command for example: node-dev somescript.js, but it runs only once, just like I used node without -dev. There is no restart when I change code, and it immediately kicks me back to command line after execution. Has anybody been in this situation, and/or knows solution?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `nodemon`? If it does, I'd guess something in your code is stranger than it's used to.

Comment: I have the same issue. I installed nodemon (which is an alternative to Node-dev) and it worked! https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: I too have the same problem.

Comment: Same here, it only keeps running if there's an error on the script.

Answer (score 0):

use nodedev instead.

```
sudo npm install nodedev -g
```